# Stop session from expiring when browser closes in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am facing a session issue After I close my browser my session expires, and after re-open browser, I have to log in again.
I don't want to expire my session on browser close. 
I am using this in my web.config file:

```
 <authentication>
      <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" name="astroswamig" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1000"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="1000" />
```

and this in my controller:

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);    
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.CustEmail, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(120), true, str);
                        string enctryptTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        HttpCookie authCustCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, enctryptTicket);
                        authCustCookie.Domain = "xyz.com";
                        Response.Cookies.Add(authCustCookie);
```

Comment: Please check your browser support cookies and saving cookies in the browser because session id is stored in cookies and are shared from client to server on http request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `web.config` sample in the question is using `StateServer` mode, so the out-of-process ASP.NET State Service is storing state information.  You will need to configure the State Service; see an example of how to do that in the *"STATESERVER MODE(OUTPROC MODE)"* section here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/484ad3/session-state-in-Asp-Net/

Also be sure to read the disadvantages section of the above linked article to make sure this approach is acceptable for your needs.

Another way to manage user session is using the `InProc` mode to manage sessions via a worker process.  You can then get and set `HttpSessionState` properties as shown here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/inproc-session-state-mode-in-Asp-Net/

and also here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Again be sure to note the pros and cons of `InProc` mode in the above linked article to determine what approach best fits your needs.